# Csv file column calculation

Tags: bash, csv

In csv file I have below columns and I try to change the second column's value with

```
$ awk -v FS="\",\"" -v OFS="\",\"" '{$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2*2)}1' file.csv
```

But some columns contains string which must remain unchanged. I know

```
"^[0-9][0-9]*$"
```

will check if it is number but how to combine it in my command?

file.csv

```
"sku","NO price","supplierName"
"sku","3.14","supplierName"
"sku","3.56","supplierName"
"sku","4.20","supplierName"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -v FS='","' -v OFS='","' '$2+0 == $2{$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2*2)}1' file.csv
"sku","NO price","supplierName"
"sku","6.28","supplierName"
"sku","7.12","supplierName"
"sku","8.40","supplierName"
```

`$2+0 == $2` check makes sure that value in `$2` is numeric.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131073/awk-printf-number-in-width-and-round-it-up)

Comment: Please post a new question for rounding of floating point number as this question was to identify numerics.